# Vue project within existing Laravel Spark site

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

I currently have a Laravel Spark website running which employs Vue 2 internally.
I am now following a Vue course for an addition to my site.

I finished 20% of the course, it covered some Vue basics and important tools like
Webpack,Babel, SASS, PostCSS, ESLint and Vue CLI. I would think it would be possible to have these tools create the final javascript/css output which could be loaded into a dedicated Laravel blade page. So ideally, I would like to develop this new Vue website separately, and just plug it into the existing Laravel Spark site without having to worry about breaking things on the Laravel Spark side. Would this be possible?

Comment: Which version of Laravel Spark are you using?

Comment: Laravel Spark version 11.0.4